# Unable to resolve dependency for libpango-1.0-0 in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, vpn, pango

Unable to resolve dependency for libpango-1.0-0 in 12.04. This is needed while installing forticlient-sslvpn

```
sudo dpkg -i forticlient-sslvpn_4.4.2312-1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package forticlient-sslvpn.
(Reading database ... 309369 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking forticlient-sslvpn (from forticlient-sslvpn_4.4.2312-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of forticlient-sslvpn:
 forticlient-sslvpn depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpango-1.0-0 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing forticlient-sslvpn (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 forticlient-sslvpn
```

Install libpango

```
sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package libpango-1.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpango-1.0-0' has no installation candidate
```

EDIT1:

```
find /usr/lib -type f -name "libpango*"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangomm-1.4.so.1.0.30
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/module-files.d/libpango1.0-0.modules
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/module-files.d/libpango1.0-0.modules
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0.3000.0
```

Comment: You first tagged and asked the question with 14.04. Why you changed it to 12.04?

Comment: @Anwar I just realized that the machine was 12.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of the package is incorrect. It should be:

```
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0
```

Comment: Looks like the package has different name in 12.04 and 14.04. Also see OPs edit

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libpango1.0-0 and  http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpango-1.0-0

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0 - this works as expected, but forticlient-sslvpn is looking for libpango-1.0.0. What should I do?

Comment: it's the same package with a different name, did you try installing the forticlient deb again @Rpj ? if you did, I am not sure how to fix it (without some dirty hacking that I wouldn't recommend)

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't help. Let me know what else I can try to get this working

Comment: @Rpj do `sudo apt-get -f install` after that. It should auto-resolve the problem

Comment: No it didn't, I already did that and it didn't help

Comment: @Rpj could you try `find /usr/lib -type f -name "libpango*"` and edit your question with the output? We might be able to fool forticlient with a symlink... also where did you download the deb?

Answer (score 7):

The deb file you downloaded is from https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/. The package maintainer there tried to build .deb files for easier installation of *Forticlient–SSLVPN* which comes with a .tar.gz package.

But I think, the package maintainer wrongly included `libpango-1.0-0` in the dependency list in packages for releases older than 15.04. `libpango-1.0-0` pulls `libpango1.0-0` package in recent releases, but in 12.04 [there is no `libpango-1.0-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpango-1.0-0&searchon=names). You need to install `libpango1.0-0` for that.

The easiest solution I think (I haven't tested this) to decompress and re-build the deb again. First remove the package using

```
sudo dpkg -P forticlient-sslvpn
```

Then proceed with these steps:

Install `dpkg-dev` package

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

Make a directory to extract

```
mkdir forticlient-sslvpn
```

Extract the deb file to it

```
dpkg-deb -R forticlient-sslvpn_4.4.2312-1_amd64.deb forticlient-sslvpn/
```

Go to the `forticlient-sslvpn/DEBIAN` folder and open `control` file. Change the `libpango-1.0-0` in the line `Depends:` to `libpango1.0-0`. Save the file.

Return back out of the `forticlient-sslvpn` directory.

Use this command to build the package again.

```
 dpkg-deb -b forticlient-sslvpn
```

This should create a deb file named `forticlient-sslvpn.deb`. Install it with

```
 sudo dpkg -i forticlient-sslvpn.deb
```

Then install any missing dependencies using

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Rpj that works!!? nice!!

Comment: Hooray! This also works for installing the current minecraft-launcher.deb downloaded from minecraft.net, on Ubuntu focal 20.04 (development release). However I needed to do the reverse transformation (.deb depends on libpango1.0-0, I needed to change to libpango-1.0-0.)

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

After:

```
sudo dokg -i anydesk
```